# MassTransit Consumer not receiving scope context from NLog MDLC

Tags: rabbitmq, nlog, masstransit, consumer

I would like to set `flowId` to MDLC before consuming an item by any of my Rabbit consumers.

At first, I called `SeMetaData` after Consume:

```
public class SomeConsumer: IConsumer<ItemDto>
{
     private IServiceLogger _logger;

     public SomeConsumer(IServiceLogger logger)
     {
          _logger = logger;
     }
     
     public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ItemDto> context)
     {
         //Set flowId
         _logger.SetMetaData(GetFlowId(context.Message));
         ...
     }
}

public class ServiceLogger : IServiceLogger
{
    public static void SetMetaData(string id)
    {
        MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("flowId", id);
    }
}
```

Since I have multiple consumers, I looked for a more generic solution so I implemented (MassTransit) IConsumeObserver, and tried `SetMetaData` on PreConsume:

```
public class ConsumeObserver : IConsumeObserver
{
    private IServiceLogger _logger;

    public ConsumeObserver(IServiceLogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task PreConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        //Set flowId
        _logger.SetMetaData(GetFlowId(context.Message));
        await context.ConsumeCompleted;
    }
    ...
}
```

But `flowId` is set only inside PreConsume. Once the item was consumed by a consumer, `flowId` was empty in the logger.

How can I set MDLC before consuming an item?

Comment: If your Rabbit-consumers are running on a dedicated threadpool, then thread-execution-context (where MDLC lives) might not transfer to the consumer-threads. Maybe use the `ConsumeContext` instead of MDLC ?

Comment: How can I use `ConsumeContext` to achieve the same functionality as MDLC provides? And also, how can I apply it to all of the consumers (pre-consume)?

Comment: MassTransit ver. 7 seems to prefer `System.DiagnosticSource.Activity.Baggage` for context-transfer. See also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md

Comment: Observers are not scoped, you would need to create a custom middleware component (such as a [Scoped Filter](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html)). There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) for this as well.